# Unknown error in LibGDX about OpenGL

Tags: android, libgdx

I trying to run first project from LibGDX, and at start i get:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: OpenGL 2.0 or higher with the FBO extension is required. OpenGL version: 1.1.0
Type: OpenGL
Version: 1:1:0
Vendor: Microsoft Corporation
Renderer: GDI Generic
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.initiateGLInstances(LwjglGraphics.java:347)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.initiateGL(LwjglGraphics.java:226)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:217)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:144)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

My OpenGL is 4.4
and i add line:

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL", "true");
```

but it did not help me, someone has an idea?

Comment: Which video card and driver version are you using?

Comment: gtx1060 and driver the latest from the nvidia website

Comment: You didn't provide the driver version as requested, so I'm going to assume that you're on driver version 378.49 (which is the "latest" on the general nvidia driver download webpage). There's an issue with driver version 378.49. Nvidia fixed it in the latest driver 378.57: http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4378/, see also: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4584

Comment: yes i had 378.49 - on the nvidia website is written " the newest", but it's a lie, this hotfix 378.57 it works, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Problem in driver version 378.49 of Nvidia

https://www.reddit.com/r/feedthebeast/comments/5pydv9/dont_install_nvidia_gpu_driver_version_37849_it/

Use GeForce Hot Fix driver version 378.57

http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4378/